# How to assert a class is decorated by a function in unit test in Python?

Tags: pytest, decorator, assertion

I have a class that is decorated by a function

```
@my_decorator('type', 'callback')
class MyClass(object):
    pass

def my_decorator(type, cb):
    def wrapper(cls):
        # do sth
        return cls
    return wrapper
```

How can I write a unit test to assert that MyClass is decorated with my_decorator with 'type' and 'callback' arguments so that it raises errors in case someone removes/modifies the decorator accidentally.

```
import my_decorator

import MyClass

def test1():
    #Want to assure MyClass is decorated with my_decorator('type', 'callback')
```